# Is it possible to create template/schema config file used it in a schroot config?

Tags: schroot

E.g. there are schroot configs:

1:

```
[release-8.i386]
personality=linux32
description=TSS version 8 on Debian Wheezy i386
directory=/chroot/release/8.i386
type=directory
users=release,balage
```

2:

```
[release-7.i386]
personality=linux32
description=TSS version 7 on Debian Wheezy i386
directory=/chroot/release/7.i386
type=directory
users=release,balage
```

It can be see, a template file could be used well:

```
[release-${VERSION}.${ARCH}]
personality=linux32
description=TSS version ${VERSION} on Debian Wheezy ${ARCH}
directory=/chroot/release/${VERSION}.${ARCH}
type=directory
users=release,balage
```

Is it possible to create such template config file and to use it in a schroot config file?